# Combining kaminari and acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, acts-as-taggable-on, kaminari

I'm trying to use both acts-as-taggable-on and kaminari on a site i'm building, and both are technically working, but the behavior is unfavorable.

Right now, my tag indeces are paginated, as they should be, but the urls are kind of ugly, looking like `/page/3?tag=herp`. The first page, and tag pages without the need for pagination, appear as `/tag/herp`. Ideally, I'd like to do `/tag/herp/page/3`.

Here is the relevant portion of my `routes.rb`:

```
root to: 'posts#index'
resources :posts do
  get 'page/:page', action: :index, on: :collection
end

match "about" => "static_pages#about", as: :about
match "portfolio" => "portfolios#index", as: :portfolio

# Tags
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag
```